# Dynamically add rows with several columns in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I managed to dynamically add rows with a single column thanks to the following code, but I would like the rows to have several columns, once of which allowing the user to enter a comment to be stored. This is the code with the single column:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.rows = [];
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(event, args) {
          $scope.addRow(args);
        });
        $scope.addRow = function(args) {
          $scope.rows.push($scope.counter + ": bottone:" + args.button + ': cambio in ' + args.value);
          $scope.counter++;
          }
       });
    </script>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="200">Logs</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows">
                <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post json data

Comment: I have no JSON data. Each row is dynamically added upon clicking a button. I would like a cell to contain a value I pass to the function and another cell with an editable textfield.

Comment: What I get from your question is on button click you want a editable text field. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a row with some content and the possibility for the user to enter a short comment in a textfield for the result.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Arashk/JDS2U/12/

Comment: Frankly I could not have it working nor understand how it relates to my case. Perhaps it is not clear what I need: just create a new row upon clicking a button with at least two cells, one I shall populate by code and the other for the user's input. I need no form.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to repeat both rows and columns, and your data has to be an array of arrays. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<script type="text/javascript">
app.controller('MainController', 
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.rows = [];
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(event, args){
            $scope.addRow(args);
        });
        $scope.addRow = function(args) {
            $scope.rows.push([args.button, args.value]);
            $scope.counter++;
        }
    }
);

</script> 
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200">Logs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="cellContent in rowContent">{{cellContent}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yet the point is that I would like to enter a textfield as the third cell where the user might add a comment to be later submitted to a DB by WebSocket and temporarily to a scope variable. Also in some way also the TH should be changed to accomodate the name of the columns. Also I am not clear what should be in [args.button, args.value] to create several columns.